# Qt Creator project wizard does not display option to create a Qt project

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, qt-creator

[image]The title says it all.

I have the latest version of MinGW installed, along with the Qt 4.8.4 SDK and Qt Creator. I am running an x64 Windows 7 machine. While installing the Qt SDK, this error did come up:

```
There is a problem with your MinGW installation:
The installer could not find a valid C:\MinGW\include\w32api.h
(The supported version is 3.2)
Do you still want to continue? (Your installation may not work)
```

But according to [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-14862.html) thread, it should not have been a problem. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to actually set up Qt so that it will allow me to use the Application project wizard. I have attached a screenshot of my template selection, and [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/figures/Qt_SDK_NewProject.png) is what I think it should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to Tools->Options->Build & Run->Kits and check that there is a Qt version set up in the kit you are using.

If not, then check the Qt versions creator detected in Tools->Options->Build & Run->Qt versions. Is the version you want to use there? If not: Add it here. Note that there are some fixes for Mingw-based Qt versions in the upcoming version 2.6.1. So if Creator just does nothing after you add your qmake, then you want to grab the latest Qt5 (pre-)releases for an early version of the new creator.

Then return to the kits page and set one of the kits to use that version. Double check the other information while there.

Now you should be able to build your project. You might need to close/reopen it though.

Answer (score 1):

First check your system environment variable having path C:\MinGW\bin

Qt projects are not appearing may be due to

1. Qt libraries not found by creator. So check in Tools->Options->Build and Run->Qt Version
   check here if any qmake.exe present or not. If not then go on 2 point below.
2. Qt Libraries are not compiled (as MinGW not working due to system path variable not set) I don't know if SDK provide compiled version or not. So fix MinGW path first then run SDK. If you found Qt libraries bin then in creator set qmake.exe in Tools->Options->Build and Run->Qt Version. Hope this may fix.